# Number of dimensions to fully embed a (possibly pseudo-) Riemannian manifold reflected in intrinsic quantities?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Say we're given a (possibly Pseudo/Semi-) Riemannian manifold $M$. There are two (equivalent) ways to go about analyzing it. The “old” way is consider it as an embedding withing a higher dimensional (possibly Pseudo/Semi-) Euclidean space. There are various theorems about how many dimensions it takes to embed a particular manifold (Nash, Whitney et cetera). Let us take EVERYTHING relevant to be $C^{\infty}$ (the embedding).

Now we can go another way and study $M$ intrinsically. Here we pull out the Riemann and Ricci tensors and the rest of our bag of tricks. This is the standard way of doing business these days.

Since these two approaches are equivalent, then I'm curious how the number of dimensions required for an embedding of a manifold is reflected in the curvature tensors? I find it rather interesting and would happily accept a good reference or prefferably some explanation and a reference for further reading.

NOTE: I'm studying this from a physics point of view, and am looking at how all of the frames in different places on a spacetime $M$ would be related to one another (so I'm interested in the groups over the manifold which related frames globally). This would seem to depend upon the number of dimensions required to embed it (when such frame changes are written as Clifford algebras of the embedding space).

Thank you!

Comment: First, I want to note that studying a Riemannian manifold as a submanifold in Euclidean space. If the codimension is too high, there is too much flexibility in the isometric embedding, so the extrinsic geometric properties tell you very little about the manifold itself.

Comment: There is very little understanding of how dimensions are required to embed isometrically a Riemannian manifold. There is, however, a lower bound in the dimension that depends on the Riemann curvature tensor at each point. This arises from the Gauss equations, which give a formula for the Riemann curvature in terms of the second fundamental form. In general, given a specific Riemann curvature tensor, there will be no solution to this system of equations unless the dimension of the Euclidean space is high enough.

Comment: My suggestion is to study manifolds intrinsically.

Comment: @Deane I understand. I'm interested in finding a global orthonormal basis for say an $s^{3}xs^{1}$ spacetime which is parallelizable and lives in ${R}^{4,2}$ for example. Of course ANY Lorentzian manifold can LOCALLY be described by an ${R}^{3,1}$ basis but since the latter is parallelizable I should be able to find a global basis. That seems like it would require the basis of the larger space as projected onto the subspace.

Comment: @Deane In that way I would expect an orthonormal frame at some arbitrary point on the subspace to be related to that at another point by rotation and translation in the embedding space. From a group point of view then the global orthonormal basis on the subspace would inherit SOME of the group structure of the embedding space.  Like $S^{3}$ has a basis that is SU(2) so that T(M)xT*(M) here is SO(4) which is the group of rotations of the embedding space (maybe that's just a coincidence though?)